# What is the difference between a Multi-table inherited model and a simple One-to-one relationship between the same two models?

Tags: django, inheritance, orm, model

What is the differences between these implementations? What does Django differently (beside inheriting Meta `ordering` and `get_latest_by` attribute) ?

## 1.

```
# models.py
from django.db import models

class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Restaurant(models.Model):
    place = models.OneToOneField(Place)
    serves_pizza = models.BooleanField()
```

## 2.

```
class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Restaurant(Place):
    serves_pizza = models.BooleanField()
```

## 3.

```
class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Restaurant(Place):
    place = models.OneToOneField(Place, parent_link=True)
    serves_pizza = models.BooleanField()
```

Comment: I want to extend the built in sites framework Site model with extra fields and trying to decide which method is best.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**1.** You don't really get any python inheritance, that is you can't inherit/override methods or attributes from the model class `Place` in your class `Restaurant`:

For instance:

```
class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def get_x(self):
        return 'x'

class Restaurant(models.Model):
    place = models.OneToOneField(Place)
    serves_pizza = models.BooleanField()

a_restaurant = Restaurant()
a_restaurant.get_x() # -> wouldn't work
```

This means that to obtain the `name` of a restaurant you can't do `a_restaurant.name`, you would need to follow the link: `a_restaurant.place.name`

Also note that when querying a `Place` object with the related `Restaurant`.

```
a_restaurant.save()
Place.objects.get(pk=a_restaurant.pk)  # won't work
```

You would have to write:

```
a_restaurant.save()
Place.objects.get(restaurant__pk=a_restaurant.pk)
```

---

**2 and 3**. are almost the same. You do get real python inheritance with these.

```
a_restaurant = Restaurant()
a_restaurant.get_x() # would actually work and print 'x'
```

Your model class `Restaurant` inherits everything from `Place`: model fields, normal instance/class attributes, managers, methods... and you can also override almost anything of these:
**You can't override field attributes, that's not supported.**

So now you can get the values of the fields from the parent model directly:`a_restaurant.name` because they are inherited.

Since with these implementation a `Restaurant` **is** a also `Place` you can query for a `Place` object with `Restaurant` data:

```
a_restaurant.save()
the_place = Place.objects.get(pk=a_restaurant.pk)  
# ^ this works now and returns the equivalent `Place` instance.
the_same_restaurant = the_place.restaurant
```

---

The **difference** between 2 and 3 is easier to see if you give a different name to the field:

```
class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Restaurant(Place):
    where = models.OneToOneField(Place, parent_link=True)
    serves_pizza = models.BooleanField()
```

Works exactly the same but to obtain the parent place of a `Restaurant` the attribute name is `where`:

```
the_place = a_restaurant.where
```

with **2** would have been:

```
the_place = a_restaurant.place_ptr
```

These means that `place = models.OneToOneField(Place, parent_link=True)` will only change the name of the link to the parent model instance. The default name is `'{lowercase_model_name}_ptr'`.

---

Last example:

With **1**:

```
place1 = Place.objects.create(name='place_1')
place2 = Place.objects.create(name='place_2')
restaurant1 = Restaurant.objects.create(place=place1, serves_pizza=True)

print Place.objects.all() # prints [place1, place2]
print Restaurant.objects.all() # prints [restaurant1]
```

With **2-3**:

```
place1 = Place.objects.create(name='place_1')
place2 = Place.objects.create(name='place_2')
restaurant1 = Restaurant.objects.create(name='place_3', serves_pizza=True)

print Place.objects.all() # prints [place1, place2, place3]
print Restaurant.objects.all() # prints [restaurant1]
```

---

Hope these helps. It grow a bit too long :/

Comment: My personal opinion: the 2º option seems the best implementation for this example because a `Restaurant` is indeed a `Place`.

Comment: very nice explanation, I didn't expected this long :) thank you!

Comment: One notice: Default name for the OneToOneField from the child model is `objectname.parentobject_ptr` (not objectname.parentobject) in Django 1.5. So you can query the Place with `a_restaurant.place_ptr` in #2.
But the other way around (query from place) it's: `a_place.restaurant`

Comment: @Adrian You would have to write:

a_restaurant.save()
Place.objects.get(restaurant__pk=a_restaurant.pk)

I don't understand how we can write restaurant__pk if Restaurants derive from/contain places, and not the other way round. Thanks

Comment: @dowjones123 Django can follow (and query) relationships backwards. Have a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward , https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#one-to-one-relationships and specially https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#how-are-the-backward-relationships-possible

Comment: @Adrián This is great. Perfect explanation that I was looking for. Though I do not understand any usecase/requirement of 3rd option. The main thing to be learned is "when you extend a model and get it's objects, the returned list will also contain all the child objects".

Answer (score 3):

1 - to create restaurant you need to create place, after create restaurant, after link them,
2 - then creating restaurant, new place created and linked automaticaly,
3 - you renamed parent link to place.

Using Model Inheriting with Content Types you can list all Cafes, Restaurants, Bars, etc iterating on Place.objects.all()